# GOOGLE sheets: search pair of values in two column to match and get value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I a GOOGLE sheets, I need to search for a pair of values in two column to match and get value.

Take a look at this capture to see what I mean:

[image]

I tried with `=VLOOKUP(B2:C2;F:G;E:E)` in this google sheets document (anyone can edit): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2VPUvxJIZxIY1cqbgsoDnja2g1pmw19ScNA1JLQ1mg/edit?usp=sharing but it not working.

Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In A2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B)*LEN(C2:C); VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C; {F2:F&G2:G\ E2:E}; 2; 0);))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me to modify the function to also print values when the second value (color column) is empty? I modified the Sheet to add values in rows 6 and 7 but the values '2003' and '2004' are not printed in column A: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2VPUvxJIZxIY1cqbgsoDnja2g1pmw19ScNA1JLQ1mg/edit#gid=1207376015

Comment: In that case, change the formula to =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B); VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C; {F2:F&G2:G\ E2:E}; 2; 0);))

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I got an error with this formula. Discovered that I need to replace the backslash with a comma.

Comment: @JPV , what does this part of the formula do: IF(LEN(B2:B)*LEN(C2:C)

Comment: @TimB: It checks if there are values in B and C.

Comment: Thanks @TimB, I was stuck on this because Google sheet kept throwing a parse error. Changed the \ to a , and it worked!